# what protocol must use for broadcast live video?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, udp, rtsp

A server is in the middle
And we want you to send live video to it

And on the other hand, watch it through the HTTPS like https://server/live.pm4

[image]

What protocols can be used for this purpose?

I used to do this experimentally with nodejs dgram and ffmpeg on the raw UDP and it worked fine !
but stability and security is an issue that must be observed !

Answer (score 1):

Most live (or VOD) video, for services where quality is important and/or there are a large number or users, use Adaptive Bit Rate streaming protocols at this time.

The two leading ones are HLS and MPEG DASH.

As a very high level general rule, noting that there are exceptions:

- Android, Chrome Browser, Edge Browser - use MPEG DASH
- iOS, Safari browser - use HLS

The introduction of CMAF () has consolidated the two formats making life for service provider easier, and the media streams can be the same for both and just tine manifest of index files to the streams are specific to DASH and HLS. Unfortunately, encrypted stream support for CMAF is not yet rolled out across all consumer devices so many services cannot use it fully yet.

On the security side, nearly all services use DRM to encrypt content and control entitlements. The leading DRM's are Google Widevine, Apple FairPlay and Microsoft PlayReady. Again, these are generally platform specific, with the usual use being:

- Android, Chrome browser - Widevine
- Edge Browser, X-Box - PlayReady
- iOS, Safari - FairPlay